# Find average molecular speed in gas when temperature doubles?

Tags: physics

I have the following formula.
[image]
The task just says what happens to average speed of the molecules in a gas when the absolute temperature doubles? I don't know how to go about tasks like this. What am I to solve for to hopefully find something like this:  T = factor * speed. I'm not comfortable just multiplying with two on the left side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would begin by isolating $v$. We have
$$\frac{3Tk}{m} = v^2 \implies v = \sqrt{\frac{3Tk}{m}}$$
so for a given $T$, we know how to find $v$. What happens if we substitute $2T$ for $T$? What extra factor do we gain?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ ? I think..

Comment: Yes, that's it. Every time your temperature doubles, your speed increases by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply by $2$ on both sides.  $\frac 32 \times 2=3,\ \frac 12 \times 2=1$  then you want to isolate $v$ as that is the output you are being asked for, not $T$ which is the input.

Comment: I found the comment on input and output useful so thanks.